pdf thumbnails and manifest V3 chrome extension
The goal is to allow V3 chrome extension render pdf thumbnails (first page only).
V3 has strict rules, the code of the extension should be visible. Can i use libraries, like pdf.js which use WebAssembly in my extension for the rendering? can google reject my extension for that?

WASM is allowed in the web store.
